# How to select a child node by conditionally excluding a parents previous sibling

Tags: html, dom, testing, selenium, xpath

I have a question regarding using (what is to me) some complex XPath queries in Selenium IDE (thought they do apply to XPath in general).

Firstly, here is my scenario.

I'm writing some automated tests for a feature of a website I am working on that only certain items for sale on the website have.  I'm trying to engineer the test in such a way that changes in data will not break it.  Here is an abstraction of what I'm testing:

Given a set of search results, certain products within the results will have a feature (let's call the feature attributes), I want to click on the first result (which may change in the future) that has a single price and attributes.

I am using Selenium IDE 2.5.0 / FF 28.

Here is a JsFiddle I created that simulates the markup / DOM structure I have to work with (the markup cannot be changed): http://jsfiddle.net/xDaevax/3qUHB/6/

Here is my XPath query:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'primary')]//div[contains(@class, 'results')]//div[@class='price-range']/span[not(contains(@class, 'seperate'))]/../../..//a[@class='detail-link']
```

**Essentially, the problem is this: All three have the same wrapping markup and css class information, but they differ in the price-range class due to the second element (the one I'm after) does not have "separate" or "minimum" CSS class elements.**

I have made it this far with the XPath selector, but am stuck.  I assume that when I traverse back up the DOM with the "/../..", I am losing the conditional XPath clause I previously used.

I apologize for the vagueness of the details, but due to contractual restrictions, I'm being as generic as possible.
Any suggestions on how to achieve the selection I want would be greatly appreciated.  Please let me know if I need to clarify any of the requirements or steps I have tried.

**Edit:**
Here is a succinct description of the desired outcome.

In the markup example given, I want to select and click the link in the middle result element only.  This is because the middle element has the desired "attributes" that once the link is clicked, it will take you to the product page which has additional things needing tested.  That being said, the data could change: today it is the second element in the list, but maybe tomorrow it is the 7th element of 16 total elements.

My current logic for the XPath (though my solution does not work) is as follows: The element I am interested in is distinguishable from the other results because of two things: 1), it has a detail hyperlink (that will later be clicked) and 2) it does not have a range of prices (unlike the first result).  Because the first result also has a hyperlink, the only difference between the two is that the first result has a minimum and separator markup element, while the second does not (my target link will always have a single price and not a range).  Based on this information, I tried to write XPath that will **select the first hyperlink that is not contained within an element that has a price range.**

Comment: Your current XPath selects two `a` elements. What is (or are) the elements you wish to select, in your example? And what are the criteria (can you clearly describe the rule for selecting them)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression will select all three `div` elements:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'primary')]
   //div[contains(@class, 'results')]
   //div[@class='price-range']
```

If I understood your requirements correctly, the `price-range` `div` must have a sibling that is an `<a href>` element, so we can filter out the last `div` by adding that restriction in a predicate: `[../a[@href]]`. So this expression selects only the first two `div`s:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'primary')]
   //div[contains(@class, 'results')]
   //div[@class='price-range']
        [../a[@href]]
```

Now you can add one more predicate to remove the items that don't have a single price. You chose the `separate` class as the criterion, so we can change that last predicate and add another restriction to it: `[../a[@href] and not(span[contains(@class,'separate')])]`. Now your expression selects the `div` that you want:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'primary')]
   //div[contains(@class, 'results')]
   //div[@class='price-range']
        [../a[@href] and not(span[contains(@class,'separate')])]
```

This is a location path, which creates a context. From this context, you can navigate anywhere you want. You can get the sibling `<a href>` adding a new step with its relative path: `../a`. So, finally, this expression selects the link at the same level as your `div`:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'primary')]
    //div[contains(@class, 'results')]
    //div[@class='price-range']
         [../a[@href] and not(span[contains(@class,'separate')])]
    /../a
```

Or in one line:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'primary')]//div[contains(@class, 'results')]//div[@class='price-range'][../a[@href] and not(span[contains(@class,'separate')])]/../a
```

Comment: Fantastic Answer!  Thanks also for the detailed explanation of what each portion of the query is doing.  Onward now to see if I can get into any more trouble.